# Do someone understand what the authors mean? - a very strange notation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I'm reading the paper *Estimation of (near) low-rank matrices with noise and high-dimensional scaling* and came across a very very odd notation. I'll quote the entire passage:

> Any matrix $\Theta^*\in \mathbb R^{m_1\times m_2}$ has a singular value decomposition of the form $\Theta^*=UDV^T,$ where $U\in \mathbb R^{m_1 \times m_1}$ and $V\in \mathbb R^{m_2 \times m_2}$ are orthonormal matrices. For each integer $r\in \{1,2,\ldots, m:=\mathrm{min(m_1, m_2)} \}$ we let $U^r \in \mathbb R^{m_1 \times r}$ and $V^r \in \mathbb R^{m_2 \times r}$ be the sub-matrices of singular vectors associated with the top $r$ singular values of $\Theta^*$. We then define the following two subspaces of $\mathbb R^{m1 \times m_2}$:
> $$\mathcal {A}(U^r , V^r):=\{ \Delta \in \mathbb R^{m_1 \times m_2 }; \mathrm{row}(\Delta) \subseteq V^r \mathrm{and}\ \mathrm{col}(\Delta) \subseteq U^r   \},$$
> $$\mathcal {B}(U^r , V^r):=\{ \Delta \in \mathbb R^{m_1 \times m_2 }; \mathrm{row}(\Delta) \perp V^r \mathrm{and}\ \mathrm{col}(\Delta) \perp U^r   \},$$
> where $\mathrm{row}(\Delta) \subseteq \mathbb R ^{m_2}$ and $\mathrm {col}(\Delta) \subseteq \mathbb R^{m_1}$ denote the row space and column space, respectively, of the matrix $\Delta$.

I know what $\mathrm{row}(\Delta)$ and $\mathrm{col}(\Delta)$ are and understand the notation $\mathrm{row}(\Delta) \subseteq \mathbb R ^{m_2}$ and $\mathrm {col}(\Delta) \subseteq \mathbb R^{m_1}$, but since $U^r$ and $V^r$ are matrices I have no idea what $\mathrm{row}(\Delta) \subseteq V^r$, $\mathrm{row}(\Delta) \perp V^r$ etc. means. How can a vector subspace in $\mathbb R^n$ be a subset of or to be orthogonal to a matrix?! Do someone have and idea what the authors meant? Could you explain it to me? Please help.

Comment: I believe they mean column space.

Comment: @gunes have you ever encountered such annoying notation?

Comment: I havent to be honest

Comment: @gunes when I'm looking now you may be right, because $col(V^r) \subseteq \mathbb R^{m_2}$ and $col(U^r) \subseteq \mathbb R^{m_1}$ i.e. the dimensions of the subspaces in the definition are ok. Thank you for your help. After many papers and textbooks I'm very liberal with regard to the notation, but these folks exagerrated.